# RMagick Rounded Corners

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

Need a simple a way of rounding off an Image. I need the corners to be transparent. This link shows how to do it via command line:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#rounded

What I need is the corresponding RMagick\Ruby code... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using paperclip, check http://loo.no/articles/rounded-corners-with-paperclip

Comment: was using a hand-rolled image solution, but perhaps I'll switch over to paperclip. thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Include Rmagick in your source code. Be sure to place the include inside the class declaration.

```
require 'rmagick'
include Magick
```

Create a method, like this

```
def thumb(source_image, geometry_string, radius = 10)
  source_image.change_geometry(geometry_string) do |cols, rows, img| 

    # Make a resized copy of the image
    thumb = img.resize(cols, rows)

    # Set a transparent background: pixels that are transparent will be
    # discarded from the source image.
    mask = Image.new(cols, rows) {self.background_color = 'transparent'}

    # Create a white rectangle with rounded corners. This will become the
    # mask for the area you want to retain in the original image.
    Draw.new.stroke('none').stroke_width(0).fill('white').
        roundrectangle(0, 0, cols, rows, radius, radius).
        draw(mask)

    # Apply the mask and write it out
    thumb.composite!(mask, 0, 0, Magick::CopyOpacityCompositeOp)
    thumb
  end
end
```

Call the method like this

```
source_image = Image.read('my-big-image.jpg').first
thumbnail_image = thumb(source_image, '64x64>', 8)
thumbnail_image.write('thumb.png')
```

I structured it this way because I already have the image open for another purpose at the point I'm creating the thumbnail. It might make more sense for you to put the file operations right in the method.

Also, you might want to look at how geometry strings work http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/imusage.html#geometry

Comment: January 2022: I had to replace "Magick::CopyOpacityCompositeOp" with "Magick::CopyAlphaCompositeOp"

Answer (score 4):

Using [Fitter Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302662/fitter-man)'s code with `CarrierWave::RMagick`

**Method:**

```
def resize_and_round(geometry_string, radius = 10)
  manipulate! do |original|
    original.change_geometry(geometry_string) do |cols, rows, img| 

      # Make a resized copy of the image
      thumb = img.resize(cols, rows)

      # Set a transparent background: pixels that are transparent will be
      # discarded from the source image.
      mask = Magick::Image.new(cols, rows) {self.background_color = 'transparent'}

      # Create a white rectangle with rounded corners. This will become the
      # mask for the area you want to retain in the original image.
      Magick::Draw.new.stroke('none').stroke_width(0).fill('white').
          roundrectangle(0, 0, cols, rows, radius, radius).
          draw(mask)

      # Apply the mask and write it out
      thumb.composite!(mask, 4,4, Magick::CopyOpacityCompositeOp)
      thumb
    end
  end
end
```

**Usage:**

```
process :resize_and_round => ['200x200', 20]
```

Answer (score 2):

In general I've had such poor luck with RMagick that I generally find it easier to just do a system() call with the command in it to modify the images. If you took that approach you could use exactly the command in the link you referenced.

Answer (score 1):

This is a method for using CarrierWave and RMagick to create rounded corners on images:

http://dmathieu.com/articles/development/create-your-own-carrierwave-processors/